# Meteor: accounts-ui Package

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, reactjs, meteor-accounts

I want to use accounts-ui package for manage accounts on my application, but it's currently a drop-down sign-in form. Does anyone know how to wrap it in a button so that when I click a button, the accounts log-in page will render?

Comment: accounts-ui is defaulted to that drop down. https://atmospheres.com/useraccounts/core has a lot of customization options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [sdybskiy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3291272/sdybskiy) already pointed out in the comments, the Meteor [`accounts-ui`](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/accounts-ui) package is limited to the drop-down form. However, you could use the [User Accounts suite](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core) to include UI templates for the Meteor's accounts module.

Currently, the following [versions](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#available-versions) are available:

- [`useraccounts:unstyled`](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/unstyled) – plain HTML & no CSS rules
- [`useraccounts:bootstrap`](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/bootstrap) – [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)
- [`useraccounts:foundation`](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/foundation) – [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)
- [`useraccounts:ionic`](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/ionic) – [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/)
- [`useraccounts:materialize`](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/materialize) – [Materialize](http://materializecss.com/)
- [`useraccounts:polymer`](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/polymer) – [Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org/)
- [`useraccounts:ratchet`](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/ratchet) – [Ratchet](http://goratchet.com/)
- [`useraccounts:semantic-ui`](https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/semantic-ui) – [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com)

If you want install the accounts suite, you just need to run:

1. `meteor add useraccounts:<version>`, for example: `useraccounts:bootstrap`.
2. `meteor add accounts-<loginService>`, for example: `accounts-password`.

Concerning routing, there are also two add ons available, [`useraccounts:iron-routing`](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/iron-routing) and [`useraccounts:flow-routing`](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/flow-routing).

So, if you want to have a button which renders the login page on click, you could use the following code example as a starting point (assuming you are using [Iron-Router](https://atmospherejs.com/cmather/iron-router) and the [`useraccounts:iron-routing`](https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/iron-routing) package):

```
<template name="home">
   <button id="login" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
</template>
```

---

```
Template.home.events({ 
  'click #login': function (event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   Router.go('/login');
});

AccountsTemplates.configureRoute('signIn', {
    name: 'signin',
    path: '/login',
    template: 'myLogin',
    layoutTemplate: 'myLayout',
    redirect: '/user-profile',
});
```